# XML/XSL Not displaying in FireFox

Tags: xml, xslt

I know it may be hard to explain without me presenting the code the reason why my XML file does not display the style from a XSL file. It works on any other browser but FF displays only the XML data with on style applied. Has anyone experienced this before? Thanks

Comment: As you have already assumed: without having anything to work on it will be difficult to help you. If it is actually a Firefox problem this question may even be offtopic since it would be related to bug of a software product and not actual coding.

Comment: The question is not offtopic if this is a Firefox problem...If this is a known issue with Firefox it may be part of the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I believe Mozilla was planning to drop built-in support for XSLT. That may now have occurred. Check with them... and check whether they have responded to all the people demanding that, if they do this, they make it easy to plug in Xylem or Saxon to restore that missing functionality.

Comment: Check the error console in Firefox whether it displays any problems that might explain the problem. If the error console is empty then show details of your code, we need to know whether you transform XML to HTML, XHTML, XML, or plain text, which `xsl:output method` you have.

Comment: Create a small example XML and XSLT that reproduces the problem and add it here